# Python spreadsheet-like formula parser?

Tags: python, excel, parsing, formula

I have a list of dictionaries such as:

```
l =[{country:'Italy',sales:100,cost:50}{country:'Italy',sales:130,cost:60}      
    {country:'Germany',sales:110,cost:50}]
```

I want a python function that takes a spreadsheet-like input **string** (please, read comments from @lott below) formula like:

```
margin = (sales-cost)/sales
```

And it gives me back:

```
l = [{country:'Italy',sales:100,cost:50,margin:1} ...]
```

Do you know of any existing library that does this? Or do you have an idea how to implement it?

I already got an idea, as you can see below, but I would like a better way to parse the formula. Something to deal with the blocks in the '()' or the like.

```
parsed_op = {'sales':1,'cost':-1}
calc_field_name = 'smi'
counter = -1
for d in data:
    counter = counter + 1
    calc = sum([float(d[item])*parsed_op[item] for item in parsed_op])
    d[calc_field_name] = calc
    del data[counter]
    data.append(d)
```

Comment: Existing library for this sort of thing: [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: pandas is way too complex and big for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the real problem is to put numbers where there are words.

One way to do that, could be with [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.sub) and some dictionary formatting *(I don't really know their real name, bute [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/string.html#format-examples) there are some examples)*.

The code:

```
import re

dct = {'country': 'Italy', 'sales': 100, 'cost': 50}
formula = 'margin = (sales-cost)/sales'

res_name,operation = formula.split('=')
num_formula = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', r'{d[\1]}', operation.strip()).format(d=dct)
num_formula  # '(100-50)/100'

dct[res_name.strip()] = eval(num_formula.format(d=dct))
```

Result:

```
{'country': 'Italy', 'cost': 50, 'margin': 0.5, 'sales': 100}
```

I used `eval()` to evaluate the numerical operations in the string. Usually the use of `eval()` is a bad practice, but here is very handy.

Anyhow, I'm sure you could replace that `eval()` evaluation with something else.

---

**Quick Explanation**

What `re.sub()` does:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', r'{d[\1]}', '(sales-cost)/sales')
'({d[sales]}-{d[cost]})/{d[sales]}'
```

- `r'([a-zA-Z]+)'` is the pattern.

  - `[a-zA-Z]` matches any alphabetic character.
  - The `+` right after tells to match *one or more*, alphabetic character in our case, toghter.
  - The brackets are for grouping. Meaning that what's inside is going to be a group. Since we have only a pair of brackets that's going to be group 1.
- `r'{d[\1]}'` is the replace.

  - `\1` stands for "put there group number 1".
  - So basically is going to wrap what's been matched with `{d[` `]}`.

To know more about the re module take a look at the [official doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html).

How the formatting works:

```
>>> '{d[first]} + {d[second]}'.format(d=dct)
'1 + 2'
```

Put this two things togheter with some [`strip()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) here and there to have clean strings, and you'll end up the code above.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I understand almost all. Just this: r'{d[\1]}'. Why "1"?

Comment: @kfk: `\1` stands for the first group: what's inside the brakets in the pattern. Giving a second look at the code I've found a bug: the match should be donw with `[a-zA-Z]` instead that with `\w`, beacuse a word character include nubers, `\w` is like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. I fixed this updating the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this and you'll be happier.

```
Metrics = namedtuple('Metrics', 'country,sales,cost' )

Margin = namedtuple( 'Margin', 'country,sales,cost,margin' )

metrics = ( Metrics(**row) for row in l ) # a one-use only generator; not a sequence
margin = [ 
    Margin( m.country, m.sales, m.cost,
       margin= (m.sales-m.cost)/m.sales 
    )
for m in metrics ]
```

This works well because your formula `margin= (m.sales-m.cost)/m.sales` is very, very easy to read, understand and modify.

Comment: yes, it's easy, but I need it to be a string formula. Imagine keys a b and c. I need to do things like: sum((a*b + c)/a)...

Comment: @kfk: Why does it need to be a string?  That seems silly.  There's no good reason for that.  If it must be a string, please **update** the question to state that very, very clearly.  Also.  Search because the "how do I evaluate a string" has been asked.

Comment: @lott: I need this in a small web app. People have to be able to add calculated columns. That can only be done passing a string formula from an input field.

Comment: @kfk: Please **update** the question to state that very, very clearly.